# MATLAB: use strcmp(s1,s2) for variable length vector with strings

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, compare

I have a query which I am trying to solve

I know that one can  use `strcmp(s1,s2)` to compare two different strings to see whether they are the same. It gives  1  if that is the case.

However, how would one tackle this problem if you have a variable length array full of strings and you want to the whether all strings in the array are the same.

For example: `['NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010'  'NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010']`  we can see that all the strings are the same in this array.  However, how would one go about with using  `strcmp(s1,s2)`.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I assume your example should be use {} instead of []? otherwise it is one string.

Comment: `numel(unique({'NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010'  'NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010'})) == 1`?

Comment: If one of the answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question. If your question is not answered, please explain what’s missing.

Answer (score 2):

You probably had a pairwise comparison using `strcmp` in mind, but you can use it directly on cell arrays:

```
x={'NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010'  'NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010'}
result=all(strcmpi(x{1},x(2:end)))
```

Compare the first element to the remaining elements. It returns true only if all elements are equal. For a pairwise comparison you could us:

```
[~,~,c]=unique(x);
result=bsxfun(@eq,c,c.')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want *all pairwise comparisons* between strings: call [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate indices of all combinations, and then index into your cell array of strings and call `strcmp`:

```
x = {'NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010'  'NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010'};
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(x));
result = strcmp(x(ii), x(jj));
```

In this case

```
result =
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
```

because all strings are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're solving the problem with a matrix (i.e. every row is a string) there are no particularly nice solutions in my opinion, but if your strings are contained into a cell array, things are getting easier and nicer.

So we start by creating such cell array:

```
myStrings={'NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010'  'NACA64A010' 'NACA64A010'};
```

where each cell contains a string. This will make your code more robust as well since every string can have a different length (this is not true if you concatenate all your strings in a matrix).
Then you specify which string you want to find inside such cell array:

```
stringThatMustBeTested='NACA64A010';
```

Now you can use `cellfun()`, which is a function that applies another function to every cell of a given cell array as follows:

```
results=cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,stringThatMustBeTested),myStrings);
```

Such line simply means "apply `strcmp()` to every generic cell `x` inside `myStrings` and compare the cell with `stringThatMustBeTested`".

Variable `results` will be a logical output in which element `j` will be true if the j-th cell in your cell array is equal to the string you want to test. If `results` is entirely composed by `1`s (which you can check as `if sum(results)==length(results)`), then all the strings are the same in `myStrings` (given that `stringThatMustBeTested` is the unique string in your cell array but anyways, this solution can be extended to a broader string search inside a cell).